# How to run a Linear Regression Model based off the frequency of events per year

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I have a data set that details thousands of soccer games globally since the 1990s. I would like to plot and then run a simple linear model of Number of `games ~ Year`.

Do I need to create a new data frame that counts the total games per year? or is there a function i can use within `lm` and `plot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to tabulate your data first.  Assuming that there is one observation per game, i.e. that the data look something like this:

```
dd <- data.frame(year=rep(1999:2002,times=c(1:3,2)),other=NA)
```

Then you need to (1) tabulate and convert to a data frame; (2) convert year back to numeric (the categories in a tabulation are always factors initially), (3) do the linear regression.

```
tt <-  as.data.frame(table(year=dd$year))
tt$year <- as.numeric(as.character(tt$year))  ## convert from factor to numeric
lm(Freq ~ year, data=tt)
```

You might want to use something like `Freq ~ I(year-min(year))` so that your intercept means something sensible (predicted number of games in the first year in the data set, rather than predicted number of games in the year AD (CE) 0).

Comment: If that solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ("thank you" comments are actually deprecated on Stack Overflow, although the sentiment is appreciated)